# Haskell Servant Get Current Route / URL From Handler

Tags: haskell, request, servant

I'd like to get current route that corresponds to my handler. Here is mockup of my server just for reference:

```
type ServerAPI = 
         "route01" :> Get '[HTML] Text
    :<|> "route02" :> "subroute" :> Get '[HTML] Text
    :<|> "route03" :> Get '[HTML] Text
```

And here are some handlers :

```
route1and2Handler :: Handler Text
route1and2Handler = do
    route <- getCurrentRoute
    addVisitCountForRouteToDatabaseOrSomethingOfThatSort...
    return template

route3Handler :: Handler Text
route3Handler = return "Hello, I'm route 03"
```

And my server :

```
server :: Server ServerAPI
server = route1and2Handler :<|> route1and2Handler :<|> route3Handler
```

So, essentially my `route1and2Handler` should have some way of getting current route. I've tried getting a request object into my handler and extracting url from that by implementing `HasServer` instance like so :

```
data FullRequest

instance HasServer a => HasServer (FullRequest :> a) where
    type Server (FullRequest :> a) = Request -> Server a
    route Proxy subserver request respond =
        route (Proxy :: Proxy a) (subserver request) request respond
```

---

**[EDIT]** I have just noticed that I was looking at api for old version of servant and this isn't valid any more. New `route` has type signature of `route :: Proxy api -> Context context -> Delayed env (Server api) -> Router env` and I don't really see way to get `Request` from here.

---

And than making `route1and2Handler` type signature to be `Request -> Handler Text`, but I'm getting this error when trying to create `HasServer` instance :

```
`Server' is not a (visible) associated type of class `HasServer'
```

**And just to point out in the end, my end goal is to get current route from within the `Handler`, adding visit count for route in the database is just for example purposes. I'm not interested in better way to count visits or something of that sort.**

Comment: The actual type family is `ServerT`, `Server` is just a convenient synonym to `ServerT` that uses the `Handler` monad.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find an answer for this? My use-case is for audit & logging.

Comment: Btw, there is a `Summary` and `Description` with `HasServer` instances - https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/servant-0.14.1/Servant-API.html#t:Summary -- is there any way to extract this text from **within** a handler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two questions in one:

1. how to get current Request or URL?
2. how to get current "route"?

Note, that URL (e.g. `/route12/42`) is different than route
(e.g. `"route12" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] Int).
Let's see how we can solve both of these questions, right after a
short language pragma and import section.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-orphans         #-}
module Main where

import Data.Maybe             (fromMaybe)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import System.Environment     (getArgs)
import GHC.Generics           (to, from, M1 (..), K1 (..), (:*:) (..))

-- for "unsafe" vault key creation
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8    as BS8
import qualified Data.Vault.Lazy          as V
import qualified Network.Wai              as Wai
import qualified Network.Wai.Handler.Warp as Warp

import Servant
import Servant.API.Generic 
import Servant.Server.Generic
import Servant.Server.Internal.RoutingApplication (passToServer)
```

### How to get current `Request` object or URL

Passing current `WAI` `Request` to the handler is actually quite easy.
This is "lazy" approach, we ask for "everything" in the request,
and we have to be careful in the handler (e.g. we cannot touch `requestBody`).
Also this "combinator" ties implementation to the `wai` server implementation,
which is an implementation detail
(nothing else in `servant-server` exposes `wai` internals, except of `Raw`).

The idea is to make `Server (Wai.Request :> api) = Wai.Request -> Server api`.
If we imagine for a second that we have such functionality in place,
we can write, using `Servant.API.Generic` (see "Using generics" cookbook recipe):

```hs
data Routes1 route = Routes1
    { route11 :: route :- Wai.Request :> "route1" :> Get '[JSON] Int
    , route12 :: route :- Wai.Request :> "route2" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] Int
    }
  deriving (Generic)

routes1 :: Routes1 AsServer
routes1 = Routes1
    { route11 = \req -> liftIO $ do
        let p = Wai.rawPathInfo req
        BS8.putStrLn p
        return (BS8.length p)
    , route12 = \req i -> liftIO $ do
        let p = Wai.rawPathInfo req
        BS8.putStrLn p
        return (succ i)
    }

app1 :: Application
app1 = genericServe routes1
```

We define a `Routes1` data type, implement `Routes1 AsServer` value and turn it
into the `wai`'s `Application`. However, to compile this example, we need an
additional instance.  We use an *internal* `passToServer` combinator in the
implementation of `route`.

```hs
instance HasServer api ctx => HasServer (Wai.Request :> api) ctx where
    type ServerT (Wai.Request :> api) m = Wai.Request -> ServerT api m

    hoistServerWithContext _ pc nt s =
        hoistServerWithContext (Proxy :: Proxy api) pc nt . s

    route _ ctx d = route (Proxy :: Proxy api) ctx $
        passToServer d id
```

This solution is good quick fix, but there are arguably better ways.

#### Specific combinator

We may notice that both our handlers use `Wai.rawPathInto req` call.
That should alert us. Specific combinator is more elegant.
An ability to create new combinators outside the core framework,
is one of design principles of `servant`.

```hs
data RawPathInfo

instance HasServer api ctx => HasServer (RawPathInfo :> api) ctx where
    type ServerT (RawPathInfo :> api) m = BS8.ByteString -> ServerT api m

    hoistServerWithContext _ pc nt s =
        hoistServerWithContext (Proxy :: Proxy api) pc nt . s

    route _ ctx d = route (Proxy :: Proxy api) ctx $
        passToServer d Wai.rawPathInfo
```

Using new `RawPathInfo` combinator, we can re-implement our application:

```hs
data Routes2 route = Routes2
    { route21 :: route :- RawPathInfo :> "route1" :> Get '[JSON] Int
    , route22 :: route :- RawPathInfo :> "route2" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] Int
    }
  deriving (Generic)

routes2 :: Routes2 AsServer
routes2 = Routes2
    { route21 = \p -> liftIO $ do
        BS8.putStrLn p
        return (BS8.length p)
    , route22 = \p i -> liftIO $ do
        BS8.putStrLn p
        return (succ i)
    }

app2 :: Application
app2 = genericServe routes2
```

This version is slightly more declarative, and handlers are more restrictive.
We moved the `rawPathInfo` selector from handlers to combinator implementation,
removed repetition.

#### Using `Vault`

The `vault` value in `wai` `Request` is not well known or used.
But in this scenario it can be useful.
Vault is explained in [Using WAI's vault for fun and profit](https://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2015/10/using-wais-vault) blog post.
It fills a "dynamic" gap of strongly typed `Request`: we can attach arbitrary data to the request,
as is common in web frameworks in a dynamically typed languages.
As `servant-server` is based on `wai`, using vault is the third answer
to the first part of the question.

We (unsafely) create a key to the vault:

```hs
rpiKey :: V.Key BS8.ByteString
rpiKey = unsafePerformIO V.newKey
```

Then we create a *middleware* which will put `rawPathInfo` into the `vault`.

```hs
middleware :: Wai.Middleware
middleware app req respond = do
    let vault' = V.insert rpiKey (Wai.rawPathInfo req) (Wai.vault req)
        req' = req { Wai.vault = vault' }
    app req' respond
```

Using this we make third variant of our application.
Note that we values might not be in the vault,
that's small functional regression.

```hs
data Routes3 route = Routes3
    { route31 :: route :- Vault :> "route1" :> Get '[JSON] Int
    , route32 :: route :- Vault :> "route2" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] Int
    }
  deriving (Generic)

routes3 :: Routes3 AsServer
routes3 = Routes3
    { route31 = \v -> liftIO $ do
        let p = fromMaybe "?" $ V.lookup rpiKey v
        BS8.putStrLn p
        return (BS8.length p)
    , route32 = \v i -> liftIO $ do
        let p = fromMaybe "?" $ V.lookup rpiKey v
        BS8.putStrLn p
        return (succ i)
    }

app3 :: Application
app3 = middleware $ genericServe routes3
```

Note: that `vault` can be used to pass information from middlewares to handlers
and from handlers to middlewares. For example, the authentication can be done
completely in the middleware, with a user information stored in the vault for
handlers to use.

### How to get current *route*?

The second part of a question, is how to get current route.
Something, we can get `route2/:id` out?
Note that handlers are *anonymous*, in the same sense functions are.
E.g. to write *recursive* anonymous functions, we can use `fix` combinator.
We can use something close to that to pass "route into itself",
using `Servant.API.Generics` we can reduce the boilerplate too.

We start with ordinary looking `Routes4` data structure.

```hs
data Routes4 route = Routes4
    { route41 :: route :- "route1" :> Get '[JSON] Int
    , route42 :: route :- "route2" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] Int
    }
  deriving (Generic)
```

But instead of making a `Routes4 AsServer` value, we'll use a different *mode*.
`AsRecServer route` is a handler which takes `route :- api` as a first
argument.  In this example we use `HasLink'`, but reader is free to use other
automatic interpretations, e.g. `servant-client` to make a proxy!

```hs
data AsRecServer route
instance GenericMode (AsRecServer route) where
    type AsRecServer route :- api = (route :- api) -> (AsServer :- api)

routes4 :: Routes4 (AsRecServer (AsLink Link))
routes4 = Routes4
    { route41 = \l -> liftIO $ do
        print l
        return 42
    , route42 = \l i -> liftIO $ do
        print (l i)
        return i
    }

app4 :: Application
app4 = genericRecServe routes4
```

The usage is very simple, unfortunately the implementation is not.

#### Hairy bits

The implementation of `genericRecServe` is intimidating.
The missing bit is a function `genericHoist`.
In short, given a function which can convert `modeA :- api` into `modeB :- api` for all `api`,
`genericHoist` converts `routes modeA` into `routes modeB`.
Maybe this function should exist in `Servant.API.Generic`?

```hs
genericHoist
    :: ( GenericMode modeA, GenericMode modeB
       , Generic (routes modeA), Generic (routes modeB)
       , GServantHoist c api modeA modeB (Rep (routes modeA)) (Rep (routes modeB))
       )
    => Proxy modeA -> Proxy modeB -> Proxy c -> Proxy api
    -> (forall api'. c api' => Proxy api' -> (modeA :- api') -> (modeB :- api'))
    -> routes modeA -> routes modeB
genericHoist pa pb pc api nt = to . gservantHoist pa pb pc api nt . from
```

`genericRecServe` is `genericHoist` precomposed with a variant of `genericServe`.
The implementation of one-liner, given a wall of constraints.

```hs
genericRecServe
    :: forall routes.
       ( HasServer (ToServantApi routes) '[]
       , GenericServant routes AsApi
       , GenericServant routes AsServer
       , GenericServant routes (AsRecServer (AsLink Link))
       , Server (ToServantApi routes) ~ ToServant routes AsServer
       , GServantHoist 
          HasLink'
          (ToServantApi routes)
          (AsRecServer (AsLink Link))
          AsServer
          (Rep (routes (AsRecServer (AsLink Link))))
          (Rep (routes AsServer))
       )
    => routes (AsRecServer (AsLink Link)) -> Application
genericRecServe
    = serve (Proxy :: Proxy (ToServantApi routes)) 
    . toServant
    . genericHoist
        (Proxy :: Proxy (AsRecServer (AsLink Link)))
        (Proxy :: Proxy AsServer)
        (Proxy :: Proxy HasLink')
        (genericApi (Proxy :: Proxy routes))
        (\p f -> f $ safeLink p p)
```

There we us single-instance-class trick to make partially applicable `HasLink`.

```hs
class (IsElem api api, HasLink api) => HasLink' api
instance (IsElem api api, HasLink api) => HasLink' api
```

The work horse of `genericHoist` is `gservantHoist` which works
on `Rep` of route structures.
It's important to notice that `c` and `api` arguments are class arguments.
This let us constraint them in instances.

```hs
class GServantHoist c api modeA modeB f g where
    gservantHoist
        :: Proxy modeA -> Proxy modeB -> Proxy c -> Proxy api
        -> (forall api'. c api' => Proxy api' -> (modeA :- api') -> (modeB :- api'))
        -> f x -> g x
```

Instance for `M1` (metadata) and `:*:` (product) are straight-forward
pass-through, something you would expect:

```hs
instance
    GServantHoist c api modeA modeB f g
    =>
    GServantHoist c api modeA modeB (M1 i j f) (M1 i' j' g)
  where
    gservantHoist pa pb pc api nt
        = M1
        . gservantHoist pa pb pc api nt
        . unM1

instance
    ( GServantHoist c apiA modeA modeB f f'
    , GServantHoist c apiB modeA modeB g g'
    ) =>
    GServantHoist c (apiA :<|> apiB) modeA modeB (f :*: g) (f' :*: g')
  where
    gservantHoist pa pb pc _ nt (f :*: g) =
        gservantHoist pa pb pc (Proxy :: Proxy apiA) nt f 
        :*:
        gservantHoist pa pb pc (Proxy :: Proxy apiB) nt g
```

The implementation for the leaf `K1` shows why we need `c` and `api`
as class arguments: here we require `c api`, and "coherence" conditions,
so `api`, `modeA`, `modeB`, `x` and `y` match.

```hs
instance
    ( c api, (modeA :- api) ~ x, (modeB :- api) ~ y )
    => GServantHoist c api modeA modeB (K1 i x) (K1 i y)
  where
    gservantHoist _pa _pb _pc api nt
        = K1
        . nt api
        . unK1
```

#### Conclusion

Using similar `Generic` approach, we can do various transformations on handlers.
For example we can wrap ordinary routes in `servant` "middleware", which would
put route information into `vault`, and that information may be used by `wai`
`Middleware` to collect statistics. This way we can make an improved version of
`servant-ekg`, as currently `servant-ekg` may get confused by overlapping routes.

### Main for testing

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        ("run1":_) -> run app1
        ("run2":_) -> run app2
        ("run3":_) -> run app3
        ("run4":_) -> run app4
        _ -> putStrLn "To run, pass 'run1' argument: cabal new-run cookbook-generic run"
  where
    run app = do
        putStrLn "Starting cookbook-current-route at http://localhost:8000"
        Warp.run 8000 app
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this automatically, but it can be done "manually" by using the [`safeLink`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.9.1.1/docs/Servant-Utils-Links.html#v:safeLink) function.

The idea is that, if you have an API

```
type ServerAPI = 
        "route01" :> Get '[HTML] Text
   :<|> "route02" :> "subroute" :> Get '[HTML] Text
   :<|> Route3

type Route3 = "route03" :> Get '[HTML] Text
```

You can pass to `safeLink` a proxy with the whole API and a proxy with the particular route, and show the resulting [`URI`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.9.1.1/docs/Servant-Utils-Links.html#t:URI):

```
show (safeLink (Proxy::Proxy ServerAPI) (Proxy::Proxy Route3))
```

If the route has parameters, you will also have to pass the parameters taken by the handler. For example:

```
type ServerAPI =
       ...
   :<|> Route4

type Route4 = "route04" :> Capture "cap" Int :> Get '[JSON] Text
```

in ghci:

```
ghci> :set -XKindSignatures -XDataKinds -XTypeOperators -XTypeFamilies
ghci> :type safeLink (Proxy::Proxy ServerAPI) (Proxy::Proxy Route4)
Int -> URI
```

---

You will  have to do this for each route.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, because you get some obscure type `MkLink endpoint Link` back, not URI.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a 'route' parameter to your handler, you could then set the parameter value via function application when you combine the handlers for your server.

Based on your example:

```
type ServerAPI = 
         "route01" :> Get '[JSON] Text
    :<|> "route02" :> "subroute" :> Get '[JSON] Text
    :<|> "route03" :> Get '[JSON] Text

route1and2Handler :: String -> Handler Text
route1and2Handler route = do
    -- addVisitCountForRouteToDatabaseOrSomethingOfThatSort...
    return (pack route)

route3Handler :: Handler Text
route3Handler = return "Hello, I'm route 03"

server :: Server ServerAPI
server = route1and2Handler "route01" :<|> route1and2Handler "route02" :<|> route3Handler
```

Alternatively, if what you are really interested in is some generic request processing for all routes, this is perhaps better achieved by applying 'middleware' between the server and the application. The middleware (usually of type `Application -> Application`) has access to the request. See [wai-extra](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra) for examples of wai middleware.

An example of performing logging for all requests:

```
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger (logStdoutDev)

...

app :: Application
app = serve serverAPI server

main :: IO ()
main = run 8081 $ logStdoutDev app
```

Comment: How will the middleware help in determining which servant route was/will-be used to serve the request? At best the middleware will give you information at solely at an HTTP level, like the request path, or the query params. What I'm interested in in determining, whether the current request was matched to `/users/:id/comments` or `/users/:id/posts`